# recursion not working as desired

Tags: ocaml

the keword rec do not do anything and do not cause any segmentation fault 
like this example

```
 let rec x x=x+x in x 2;;
 :-int=2
```

Answer (score 3):

In this definition:

```
let rec x x = x + x
```

The "recursive" function name `x` is hidden by the parameter named `x`. It's just as if you had:

```
let rec x y = let x = y in x + x
```

In essence there is an inner binding that hides the recursive one.